# PYTHON script: redirect AZ cli outputs to a file

Tags: python, output, azure-cli

This is the current python script:

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli
import argparse
import json

######credentials:
AZCLIusr = XXXXXXX
AZCLIpwd = XXXXXXXXX
AZCLItenant = XXXXXX
######resource group arg:
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--rg", help="specify Azure Resource Group")
args = parser.parse_args()
resourceGroupAZ = str(args.rg)
#######

get_default_cli().invoke(['login', '--service-principal', '--username', str(AZCLIusr), '-p', str(AZCLIpwd), '--tenant', str(AZCLItenant)])

###### AZ CLI EXECUTION QUERY


get_default_cli().invoke(['vm', 'list','--resource-group', resourceGroupAZ, '--query', '[].{Name:name, TAGS:tags, RESOURCEGROUP:resourceGroup}'])
```

this is the current output of the "vm list":

```
[
  {
    "Name": "VM-NAME",
    "RESOURCEGROUP": "RESOURCEGROUP-NAME",
    "TAGS": {
      "TAGNAME": "TAGVALUE",
      "TAGNAME": "TAGVALUE",
      "TAGNAME": "TAGVALUE"
    }
  }
]
```

If I use the execution with an output like the following:

```
python3 pythonScript.py >> file.txt
```

that includes all the outputs, including the log in JSON etc...and only wants the output "vm list".

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

We have tried with the  below code to achieve the same as per your requirement.(e.g to store the VM list in `file.txt` instead of all logs) .

***CODE:-***

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli

import argparse

import json



######credentials:

AZCLIusr = 'fxxxxxxxxxxx'

AZCLIpwd = 'xxxxxxxx'

AZCLItenant = 'xxxxxx'

######resource group arg:

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

#parser.add_argument("--rg", help="specify Azure Resource Group")

#args = parser.parse_args()

resourceGroupAZ = 'xxxx'

#str(args.rg)

#######



get_default_cli().invoke(['login', '--service-principal', '--username', str(AZCLIusr), '-p', str(AZCLIpwd), '--tenant', str(AZCLItenant) , '--output' , 'none']) ## output is none so that it silently continues to the next command



###### AZ CLI EXECUTION QUERY

get_default_cli().invoke(['vm', 'list','--resource-group', resourceGroupAZ, '--query', '[].{Name:name, TAGS:tags, RESOURCEGROUP:resourceGroup}'])
```

***OUTPUT:-***
[image]

Comment: Great!

How can you capture the result in a variable? the subprocess can´t export the az credentials

Comment: Could you please try to directly print without using silently continues.